# She lived until she was over a hundred

Tags: phrase-meaning

> She **lived until she was over a hundred**.

I have the mentioned sentence in my grammar book and I'm trying to understand its meaning.

If I understand correctly:

> She lived **until she was a hundred**. <--- she was a hundred years old in the end of her life and she died on her birthday. (I'm sorry for that example.)

> She lived **until she was over a hundred**. <--- she was more than one hundred years old in the end of her life. For example, 100 years and 1 day old; or 102 years old. Right? So, we can't say definitely how old was she. Right? Maybe, she was 110 years old. Right? We would know that definitely if there was said "She lived until she was one hundred and ten."

Is that the correct explanation?

Comment: It doesn't mean she died *on her birthday* in any of the examples, unless you explicity say, for example, "She lived until her 100th birthday."

Comment: The cited text isn't idiomatic in English. At the very least, note that we say *She lived **to be** over a hundred*. But since it's a *past tense* assertion, presumably the age she reached before dying is known at time of utterance, so I'd expect *She lived to be a hundred and five* (or perhaps something like *...to be **well over** a hundred* if speaker isn't sure of the exact age).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things.

First, **She lived until she was a hundred** means only that she was 100 years old when she died. As Weather Vane points out, no one would conclude that she had died exactly on her birthday.

Second, 100 is a very round number—you might even call it special, especially when the subject is age. If you said, **She lived until she was over 97**, your readers would conclude that she had not reached 98. But if you said **She lived until she was over a hundred,** readers would not conclude that she was  literally 100 years old plus some odd number of days. More likely, they would conclude that you had referenced **100** to emphasize her extreme age, and that in fact she might have been 1 or more years older (but probably not as old as 110).

Answer (score 3):

> She lived until she was 100.

That means she was alive when she reached 100 years old.  It doesn't say when she died.  You might guess that she died later that year.  If she had died on her birthday, that would be a surprising fact that would likely have been mentioned, and if she died more than a year later, the writer could have said "...until she was 103" for example.  However it doesn't actually say when she died.  I might use this, for example, if I know somebody had reached 100, but I wasn't certain about the exact age at which they died.

> She lived until she was over a hundred.

Means that she lived until she was *x* years old, where *x* > 100. Though some writers might use it slightly more loosely to mean where *x* ≥ 100.

In both cases the sentence tells us about when she was living. They don't tell us about when she died.

Comment: In the UK, you can buy drinks in a bar or pub if you are 'over 18'. You reach that state at 12 midnight on the night of the day before your 18th birthday, and you remain in that state until you die.